# Why are all relevant tick-marks not plotted on the X-axis?

Tags: r, plot

I often determine that when plotting in R not all relevant tick-marks are drawn. *Relevant* here means that there is data present.

See this example

```
> set.seed(NULL)
> d <- data.frame(a=sample(1:10, replace=TRUE), b=sample(11:30))
> plot(d)
```

The resulting plot where you can see values on the X-axis at 3, 5, 7 and 9. But the tick-marks for them are missing.

[image]

The focus of my question is to understand **why** R acts like that. What is the algorithm and logic behind it?

btw: I know how to solve it. I can draw the X-axis myself. But that is not part of the question.

Comment: Your definition of relevant - that there is data present - leads to a plot with full of markets, thus unable to see any of markets, when the data is dense. Of course, selectively displaying some of markers to avoid duplicate on drawing is an option, but it is not simple and may lead other hard questions. A reasonable number of uniformly distributed markers, around 5 to 10 depending on the plot and font size, seems most easiest and natural to me. Also, as like you know how, R allows to customize further for people who don't like such default option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find a brief description of the algorithm for plotting the tick marks using`?axis`.

`plot()` is a generic function to plot a wide sort of data. In your example, you are using discrete data. For continuous data, it does not make much sense to have a single tick mark for every single value, which would make unreadable the axes. 
However, you can easily adjust the ticks in your plot using `axis()`